# Django - How do I filter profile by user group?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How do I filter profile by user group?

So far I have this:

```
class StaffManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ?? # should filter user group by staff

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        to_field='id',
        primary_key=True,
        related_name='profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    staffs = StaffManager()

    def group(self):
        return ", ".join(list(self.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)))
```

Comment: What is *profile* here? it's not clear what are you trying to do

Comment: changed class to Profile. Profile meaning the extension class for User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this,

```
Profile.objects.filter(user__groups__name='My Group')
```